# Two routers connected to the same router and only one can ping another

Tags: ip, ping

There are two routers connected together to Arris TG3442 router:

- TP-Link Archer C2 AC750 (uses 192.168.1.X addressing)
- D-Link DIR-853 (uses 192.168.2.X addressing)

When I use any device in **192.168.1.X** network: I can ping any device in 192.168.2.X network *including* router itself (which sits under 192.168.2.1).

[image]

When I do the same opposite then it turns out that any device in **192.168.2.X** network can ping any device in 192.168.1.X *except* router. Any ping to 192.168.1.1 results in connection timeout

[image]

[image]

My assumptions:

- The situation is correct, no error or problem here
- The 192.168.1.1 router is most likely configured to reject ping
- But it allows ping to pass through to any device
- The 192.168.2.1 router is configured to respond to ping and pass it through.

Do I understand this situation correctly?

Comment: Are the two routers actually working as a router or a switch? Do you connect them to the Arris with their LAN port or WAN port? And where did you add the routes for the two subnets?

Comment: Both (all three?) routers are manageable (so I assume that they work as routers). Both routers has their WAN ports connected to LAN1 and LAN2 ports of Arris. The 192.168.1.X and 192.168.2.X addresses are defined in the respective router's configuration by setting "IP Address" in "LAN settings". I have no access to Arris, so I cannot configure anything there. I only know that it has DHCP enabled.

Comment: So how are their WAN configured (by the DHCP)? You should be able to see that on their admin pages. Normally `192.168.1.0/24` shouldn't be able to reach `192.168.2.0/24` (and not the other way round either). In fact both of them can use `192.168.1.0/24`, unless you disabled source NAT on both of them for their LAN clients?

Comment: I am a total newbie in networking, so my answers my not be accurate. The answer seems to be yes. Both routers have their WAN ports connected to LAN 1 and LAN 2 ports in third ("master"?) router and that router is configured to assign them IP addresses using DHCP. Currently "master" router is on `192.168.21.X` network and has assigned dynamically `192.168.21.141` to _Archer C2_ and `192.168.21.180` to _D-Ling Dir-853_. I would like to remain on separate subnets with `192.168.1.X` for Archer and `192.168.2.X` for D-Link unless the change is necessary.

Comment: I know that both shouldn't be able to reach each other and hence the question.

Comment: Have you configured any static route for `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24` on the Arris?

Comment: No, these are configured only on "second level" routers (D-Link and TP-Link) because currently I have no access to Arris configuration (I may request one, if needed).

Comment: Oh right. But do you mean you did set up some WAN side static route on the D-Link and TP-Link (like with each other's WAN IP as gateway)?

Comment: Nope, nothing was setup by me on WAN side of these two routers. It setup itself. I have limited myself into connecting them to my main router / modem and to configuring LAN side on both routers. Tom... I really appreciate your help here, but I clearly see that this has become my personal "me only" problem that only wastes your time and does not bring any serious value to the community. With all do respect, we opinion is to close this question as too narrow. I fear that, if we continue, we land in a regular forum-like post exchange, which is not a format for this site.